# Highcharts 6.0 Synchronization Bug

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, synchronization

I'm trying to use Highcharts Synchronization for a slightly complex chart. I've gotten synchronization to work just fine on graphs with just 1 series for other plots.

You can check out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhng5827/o9uh2jqy/42/

I've dumbed down my complex chart to just a few points, and usually the chart has 6 lines as opposed to 4. As you can see, the tooltip only appears on the right side of the graph, and everything is delayed. I also do not want the callout box to have any numbers read out if the tooltip is not hovered the specific lines.

I've done a fair bit of research and have implemented some code I've seen that allows for charts with 2 series to be synchronized (http://jsfiddle.net/mjsdnngq/72/), however I think the biggest difference in mine is that the series only go to about half of the actual chart.

```
    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
      var chart,
      points,
      i,
      secSeriesIndex = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
          chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
          e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
          points = [chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true), chart.series[1].searchPoint(e, true),chart.series[2].searchPoint(e, true),chart.series[3].searchPoint(e, true)]; // Get the hovered point

          if (points[0] && points[1]&& points[2]&& points[3]) {
              // if (!points[0].series.visible) {
              //     points.shift();
              //     secSeriesIndex = 0;
              // }
              // if (!points[secSeriesIndex].series.visible) {
              //     points.splice(secSeriesIndex,1);
              // }
              if (points.length) {
                  chart.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
                  chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[0]); // Show the crosshair
                  chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[3]); // Show the crosshair
              }
          }
      }
  });
 /**
  * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
  */
 Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
     return undefined;
 };
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh([points[0],points[1],points[2],points[3]]); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};
/**
 * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
 */
function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
        Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
            if (chart !== thisChart) {
                if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly synchronize charts, you have to clear points state on every mousemove event:

```
        Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(s) {
            Highcharts.each(s.points, function(p) {
                p.setState('');
            });
        });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cvb6pwsu/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

Also, please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6f37b42q/, it can be useful for you.

Comment: That looks awesome so far, thanks! Any ideas on how to get the tooltip on the left side of the graph? The gray line only stays on the right. Thanks so far!

Comment: Hi Nhi Nguyen, What exactly do you mean by tooltip on the left side of the graph? Perhaps `positioner` will solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L28y5u01/

Comment: I meant to say the crosshair, my bad. You can see that it doesn't move to the left side of the chart.

Comment: Ok, here is an example how to draw synchronized crosshair in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vpqczn3/

Comment: Thank you. And lastly, you can see that the markers for two lines don't go away when your mouse is hovering over two other lines. Do you know how to make that go away? The markers went away when I didn't add any synchronization.

Comment: Yes, you have to add some right rule, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x4qdc1b5/

Comment: Hello, there's a bug I found with toggling lines off via the legend. You can see that the marker is still visible even when you turn off the line. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to add a condition, which checks if series is visible: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s18bdmen/